# A simple contour plot of data without interpolation

Tags: plotting, visualization

I have a data set gathered from lab. The measurements are of the form `{x, y, z}`.  I want to plot this data in a way that there is (1) no interpolation between adjacent data points and (2) that is visualised in the form of cubes, i.e. `{x, y}`, and give the location of the cuboid whilst `z` gives the height, and then repeat this simply for all data points.

I have tried `ListContourPlot` and `ListDensityPlot` with `InterpolationOrder -> 0`, however I get wierd results.  For example, both plots don't show the squares or rectangular patches that I was expecting, instead they seem more triangular.

I have attached an image of a couple of my plots:

[image].

And this is the code that I have used to generate these plots:

```
GraphicsGrid[{{ListContourPlot[scanDataCh1, Mesh -> None, 
  InterpolationOrder -> 0, PlotRange -> All, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  FrameLabel -> {"Hem. Voltage (V)", 
  "Elevation Angle \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\((\), \(o\)]\))", 
  "ListContourPlot for Channel 1"}, ImageSize -> Large], 
ListDensityPlot[scanDataCh1, Mesh -> None, InterpolationOrder -> 0,
  PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  FrameLabel -> {"Hem. Voltage (V)", 
  "Elevation Angle \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\((\), \(o\)]\))", 
  "ListDensityPlot for Channel 1"}, ImageSize -> Large]}}]
```

Thanks!

Comment: ps the data set is rather large so I have not been able to include it in the post

Comment: Please include a sample of the data.

Answer (score 2):

I create some arbitrary sample data for the sake of an example:

```
hw2 = 0.02;
dat = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {20, 3}];
Graphics3D[{Cuboid[{#[[1]] - hw2, #[[2]] - hw2, 
      0}, {#[[1]] + hw2, #[[2]] + hw2, #[[3]]}]} & /@ dat]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]